# checking if array contains string or value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently working on adding an array to another array by writing something in a texfield and clicking on a button. I also have an if statement, that is supposed to check if the strings im writing already exist in the table, and if it does, i should get an alert. However, i get an alert every time i try to add something, even though my array is empty. Any solution?

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var films = [];

// ändra bakgrundsfärg för textfield 
$('#name').keyup(function(){
            $('#name').css('background-color', 'white');
});

// ändra bakgrundsfärg för select lista
$('#options').change(function(){
            $('#options').css('background-color', 'white');
});

// kör funktionen när knappen med id "button" klickas
$("#button").click(function(){
    var titelBetyg = [];

    var titel = $('#name').val();
    var betyg = $('#options').val();

    // kontrollera om textfield är tom
    if(titel == ""){
        $('#name').css('background-color', 'red');
        alert("Mata in titel.....");
    }

    // kontrollera om select lista inte är vald
    else if(betyg == "0"){
        $('#options').css('background-color', 'red');
        alert("Välj betyg....");
    }

         // HERE IS THE IF STATEMENT WHERE IT FAILS
    // kontrollera om filmen redan finns
    else if($.inArray($("#name"), films) > -1){
        alert("Filmen finns redan...");
    }

    else{
        titelBetyg.push(betyg);
        titelBetyg.push(titel);
        films.push(titelBetyg);

        var ul = $('#rightbar ul').empty();
        if (!ul.length){ // om ul inte finns
            ul = $("<ul>").appendTo('#rightbar'); // skapa en ny
        }

        // loopa igenom arrayen och placera innehållet i ul och li
        for (var i=0; i<films.length; i++){
            ul.append("<li>" + films[i][1] + " " + "<span>" + films[i][0] + "</span>" + "</li>");
        }

        $('#form').get(0).reset();

    }
});

// kör funktionen när knappen med id "stigande" klickas
 $('#stigande').click(function () {
    if (films.length > 1) {
        films.sort(function (a, b) {
            return (a[0].length < b[0].length) ? 1 : -1;
        })
        var ul = $('#rightbar ul').empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < films.length; i++) {
            ul.append("<li>" + films[i][1] + " " + "<span>" + films[i][0] + "</span>" + "</li>");
        }
    }
});

// kör funktionen när knappen med id "fallande" klickas
$('#fallande').click(function () {
    if (films.length > 1) {
        films.sort(function (a, b) {
            return (a[0].length > b[0].length) ? 1 : -1;
        })
        var ul = $('#rightbar ul').empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < films.length; i++) {
            ul.append("<li>" + films[i][1] + " " + "<span>" + films[i][0] + "</span>" + "</li>");
        }
    }
});

});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$.inArray($("#name"), films) > -1
```

You're checking if a collection of jQuery elements exists in an array, you probably meant:

```
$.inArray($.trim( $("#name").val() ), films) > -1
```

Comment: didnt help, the if statement still gave me the alert.

Comment: else if(!$.inArray($.trim($("#name").val()), films) > -1){
   alert("Filmen finns redan...");
  }

yet i still got the alert

Comment: `console.log` the value and the array and see what you've got. And if using `not`, do != -1 instead of placing the `not` at the start of the condition.

Comment: I placed the not as you said, != -1, but now it doesnt care if the value exists, it adds the new value either way.

Answer (score 1):

Is `$('#name')` an `input`? If so, you should use `$('#name').val()` instead of just `$('#name')`.